# Hiding a QWidget on a QToolbar?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, widget

I have directly added some QWidgets to a QToolbar but simply going widget->setVisible(false) did not work. Can someone please give me an example of how to show and hide a widget that is on a QToolbar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to call `setVisible()` on the appropriate QAction instead. For example, `addWidget()` returns a QAction*:

```
QAction* widgetAction = toolBar->addWidget(someWidget);
widgetAction->setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it returned a QAction on the addWidget! So much for knowing how to read simple API docs.

Comment: Haha. I googled around for this problem and came upon this answer. I had already +1ed the question and answer some time back, but I had forgotten over time. I'd +2 if I could. :-)

Comment: What a convoluted API decision.